# Faà di Bruno formula

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f,g$ be smooth functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Then
$$
\frac{(g\circ f)^{(n)}}{n!}=\sum_{1\le r\le n}\frac{(g^{(r)}\circ f)}{r!}
\sum_{\substack{(n_1,\dots, n_r)\in {\mathbb N^*}^r\\n_1+\dots+n_r=n}}\prod_{1\le j\le r}
\frac{f^{(n_j)}}{n_j!},
\tag{$\ast$}$$
is a way to write the so-called Faà di Bruno Formula. However that formula is usually written in a more complicated (equivalent)
way which is
$$
\frac{(g\circ f)^{(n)}}{n!}=\sum_{\substack{l_1+2l_2+\dots +nl_n=n\\r=l_1+\dots+l_n}}\frac{g^{(r)}\circ f}{l_1!\dots l_n! }\prod_{1\le j\le n}
\left(\frac{f^{(j)}}{j!}\right)^{l_j}.
\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$
My question: it seems that $(\ast)$ is quite easy to memorize whereas $(\ast\ast)$ is hard to recall
and also that $(\ast)$ is handy to prove that Gevrey functions ($s\ge 1$, Gevrey of index 1 is analytic functions) make an algebra for composition.
Why is $(\ast\ast)$ so popular and $(\ast)$ is absent from the literature?

Comment: See https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00950525/document

Comment: Because it is usual to collect proportional terms. Say, formula $(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+yx+y^2$ is less popular than $x^2+2xy+y^2$.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov Yes, but if you want to prove that $G^{s}$ is a composition  algebra for $s\ge 1$, $(\ast)$ is easier to use than $(\ast\ast)$.

Comment: @Bazin I agree that the first formula may be more appropriate in some situations (moreover, I personally always prefer it myself). But the explanation why it is less popular looks to be just as said.

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand the need to memorise. Either way, this formula is immediate from the Taylor formula and the multinomial theorem (for which reason the comment of Fedor Petrov is even more to the point than it may appear at a first glance), and attempting to memorise is the easiest way to get some bits wrong.

Comment: A variant of (*) that I find even more clear is to use set partitions as index set.